# Use OpenWebrtc to stream OpenCV video

Tags: c++, opencv, webrtc

I'm trying to stream a video generated with OpenCV (using the webcam and doing some image processing). To enhance the challenge, we've decided to use [OpenWebRTC](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc/). The OpenWebRTC examples are amazing, but they all use the webcam (I know, this is how webrtc is intended, to use the webcam), but we want to send Mat objects inside a while loop (very OpenCV style).

By chance, has anyone accomplished this or has any idea?

Thanks in advance,

—N

Comment: since OpenWebrtc utilizes gstreamer for most if not all of its media handling, you could probably use the [gstreamer element appsrc](http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gst-plugins-base-libs/html/gst-plugins-base-libs-appsrc.html) and push the buffers then allow the rest of the pipeline take care of the rest. You can see the video source logic in [here](https://github.com/EricssonResearch/openwebrtc/blob/master/local/owr_local_media_source.c) and just replace the element that grabs the camera with an appsrc and handle the needed callbacks

Comment: thanks! Will try it out and comment on the result